# Data persistence for sending customer emails

Tags: c#

I'm developing a system to handle sending transactional emails to our customers.
This is how it works:
1. An event occurs during the order's life cycle, for example 'shipped'
2. This event will trigger the creation of an email in the database (email queue)
3. A separate windows service is polling the db table for new emails to send.  When it finds one it calls a Web service with all the required data. It's the Web service's responsibility to handle the actual sending of the email.
My question relates to step 2.
When an email triggering event occurs, should I take a snapshot of all the data required by the service (thereby duplicating data and introducing new tables) or should I get the required data from the transactional db tables only at the point where I'm ready to call the Web service.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software design, not a problem during implementation. Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Do you want to reuse your mailing service for other purposes, or do you want it only to be able to mail order changes? If the former, another process should retrieve the data and fill in the mail body, so the mailing service can be simpler.

Comment: The part I'm involved with is purely notifying customers of the status of their order and nothing else.  Is it possible to move the thread to another forum?

Comment: _For now_. It simplifies implementation and testability to separate the concerns. Make a notifier that prepares email bodies and a mailing service that just sends those bodies. And no, you can't move.

Comment: The thing is I'm not at all concerned with the body of the email, all I'm doing is passing the data to a Web service.  The email templates etc are handled by another system.  My concern is purely to queue the email notification and pass the required data to the Web service.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depend on your data volume. If you have large amount of data then go with first solution that is de-normalize data in another separate table (you may have duplication) and then send email.